# MediaPlayer keeps freezing on pre L devices

Tags: android

I am developing a MediaPlayer in android and so far now I have tested my application on lollipop, LG G3, S5 etc.
I found a problem when I runned my app on a pre L device ( an S4 mini running 4.4.2 ). When a music starts, because I play it from an URL it's start playing like 2-3 seconds and stop for a very short time and after it's playing again and so on.

Reading again the main tutorial from android.developers, I found that I can block the main UI so I need to run the media player in a service.

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.action.PLAY";
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
            mMediaPlayer = ... // initialize it here
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
        }
    }

    /** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
    }
}
```

If this is the solution I don't really understand how I can do it, my media player is currenyl running in a `thread` in my activity.

Comment: Assuming you have subclassed AsyncTask ,there should be a @Override method 'doInBackground()'  which is designed to process its work on a different thread. Start your player from there. If you dont know what Im talking about let me know I'll post an example code

Comment: Yes, please post an example, would be very good.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by calling .prepareAsync() method after setting dataSource and prepare.